# Bootstrap Icon & Text Alignment

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to control the margin of the image by lining the image up to the headline with a ml-4. However when I try to do so, it breaks the layout. I'm noticing I can't control the space between the image and the text too, would like to close the gap a little between the Icon and the Text.

Excuse my poorly drawn pink line, but I was trying to demonstrate that I needed this to line up with the headline.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-980" style="background-color: #009DD6;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <p class="subheader text-left mt-4 ml-2 mb-4 headline">Headline</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-2 ml-4"><img class="rounded-circle float-center align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF"></div>
              <div class="col-10 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2">
                <p class="bodywhite mr-3 pull-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-3 text-center"><img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF"></div>
              <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
                <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-3 text-center"><img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF"></div>
              <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
                <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-3 text-center"><img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF"></div>
              <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
                <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
              <div class="col-3 text-center"><img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF"></div>
              <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
                <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 right_text_blue d-none d-md-block">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think the best way is to display all rows in a flex container where you would use d-flex flex-column classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Columns set differently. This is your example, you have the first placeholder set to col-2 and the following placeholders as col-3

```
<div class="row mb-3">
   <div class="col-2 ml-4">
      <img class="rounded-circle float-center align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF">
   </div>
   <div class="col-10 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2">
      <p class="bodywhite mr-3 pull-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
   <div class="col-3 text-center">
      <img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF">
   </div>
   <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
      <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

You need to change the col-3's to col-2 to get it to align. https://i.stack.imgur.com/niBNc.jpg

```
<div class="row mb-3">
   <div class="col-2 ml-4">
      <img class="rounded-circle float-center align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF">
   </div>
   <div class="col-10 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2">
      <p class="bodywhite mr-3 pull-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
   <div class="col-2 text-center">
      <img class="ml-4 rounded-circle align-items-center fluid-img" alt="placeholder image 100x100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40/FFFFFF">
   </div>
   <div class="col-9 pl-sm-0 pl-xs-2 pl-3">
      <p class="bodywhite  mr-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```